# How to set max ticks count in chart.js 3.*.*

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

How set min - max ticks count for this chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l436K.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So. I find this in inretfaces of charts

```
// Maximum number of ticks and gridlines to show.
@default 11
maxTicksLimit: number;
```

We can use this for set max ticks count.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).